# How to integrate Whatsapp in a web site

Tags: android, ios, integration, whatsapp

Is there a command to start a WhatsApp conversation on a website?

I'd prefer to have contact via WhatsApp instead clients calling me.

I tried this

```
<a href="intent://send/0123456789#Intent; scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp; action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">
```

But it doesn't work for IOS and windows mobile.

Comment: iPhone and Windows Mobile don't use Intents, so its not a surprise that your code does not work in those devices...

Comment: Fustigador have you any ideas to help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Aside the fact that there is a client of whatsapp for windows. And if you want them to contact you by whatsapp...just ask them to do so.